# Cannot create branch on Gerrit

Tags: permissions, gerrit

I am not able to create remote branches on Gerrit. The project configuration is as follows

```
Reference:  
refs/heads/*

Create Reference 
Owners

Reference
refs/heads/work_*

Create Reference
Owners
Developers
```

I'm trying to create the branch by pushing from git:

```
git push origin refs/heads/work_foo
```

But I get error 403 permission denied.

If `Developers` are allowed to create references, why am I not allowed to do it?

It does work if I have it like this:

```
refs/heads/work/*
```

But for other reasons I cannot have a slash in the branch name so I'd like to keep the `work_*` pattern.